# xlwings syntax for n-rows and specific columns with output to new sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I've been trying to find a good resource for the syntax needed with xlwings and have been unsuccessful. I am trying to make a program that will repeat for n rows of data and output certain information to a new sheet. Here is a snippet of the algorithm. If you can point me to a good reference or just lend a hand I'd be grateful.

```
data = number of rows in worksheet #either input the number manually or automate 

for row n to data: #start at row 1 and loop through each line of data

    axles = get row n, column M data #retrieve data in column M 
    if axles<2: #Test the data from column M for validity 
        continue #return to the for loop and start on next line

    distance = get row n, column Q data #retrieve data in column Q 
    if distance < 100 or distance > 300: #test the data from column Q for validity
        continue #return to the for loop and start on next line

    weight = get row n, column P data #retrieve data in column P 
    print weight into row n, column A on sheet 2 #display output on a new sheet
```

Answer (score 1):

xlwings is a pretty cool interface to excel- the `Range` object will be doing the heavy lifting for your application.  Depending on if your columns are all togetether, you could use either the `table` or `vertical` methods to read in all together or column wise.  Here are two equivalent approaches for a simple set of data in Excel:

```
axles   distance    weight
1       150         1.5
2       200         2
1       250         2.5
2       300         3
4       350         3.5
```

The python code is:

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

wb=Workbook(r'C:\\Full\\Path\\to\\Book1.xlsx')

# Method 1:
# if your table is all together read it in at once:
# read all data in as table
allrows=Range('Sheet1','A2').table.value 
for rownum, row in enumerate(allrows):
    axles=row[0]
    if axles<2:
        continue
    distance=row[1]
    if distance< 100 or distance>300:
        continue
    weight = row[2]
    # +2 to correct for python indexing and header row
    Range('Sheet2',(rownum+2,1)).value=weight 

# Method 2:
# if your columns are separated read them individually:
# read all data in as columns
axles=Range('Sheet1','A2').vertical.value 
distance=Range('Sheet1','B2').vertical.value
weight=Range('Sheet1','C2').vertical.value
# in case the columns have different lengths, look at the shortest one
for rownum in range(min(len(axles),len(distance),len(weight))):
    if axles[rownum]<2:
        continue
    if distance[rownum]< 100 or distance[rownum]>300:
        continue
    # +2 to correct for python indexing and header row
    Range('Sheet2',(rownum+2,1)).value=weight[rownum]
```

In either case the second and fourth data points will be written to Sheet 2 on the same rows as in Sheet 1

Answer (score -1):

`xlwings` is a package for the `Python` programming language. To learn Python, you can have a start on the official site, for example: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/